# window.location - open with scroll enabled

Tags: javascript

I'm using the folowing code to open a window and would like to add a scroll bar to the open window. Is it possible?

```
<input type="button" value="Download PostCode Info" onclick="window.location = 'post_code_info.html';">
```

Comment: a scroll bar only appears if the contained content extends past the visible display area. I.E. Altering your browsers dimensions.

Answer (score 0):

Basically you are redirecting the page to new location. are you trying to open a popup window ?
if so use

```
window.open(url,name,specs)
```

in specs you can specify scrollbars=yes|no|1|0